# Why would a certificate authority have multiple root certificates?

Tags: tls, certificates, web-browser, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority

When I look at the trusted certificates in my browser, I see that many certificate authorities have multiple root certificates associated with them. For example, `org-Amazon` has `Amazon Root CA 1`, `Amazon Root CA 2`, `Amazon Root CA 3`, and `Amazon Root CA 4`.

How do the purposes of these four certificates differ?

I also see that some CAs have root certificates of different "tiers", such as `gold`, `silver`, and `platinum`. What's the deal with these? I imagine there are price differences associated with the different tiers, but what extra service could they be offering?

Comment: Good question. I gave some details regarding Amazon below. I suggest you split off the gold/silver/platinum part into a question of its own so that it can be answered separately.

Answer (score 7):

Numerous public CAs have multiple root certificates in trust store for different reasons and largely depends on their business operations. Often roots from same vendor differ by:

- List of usages
- Public key or signature algorithm support
- Assurance level
- Redundancy

For example, `Amazon Root CA 2` and `Amazon Root CA 4` allows `Code Signing` certificates in their chains, while `Amazon Root CA 1` and `Amazon Root CA 3` do not allow such. This is "EKU" separation.

`Amazon Root CA 1` and `Amazon Root CA 3` share same list of usages, but they use different public key and signature algorithms: `Amazon Root CA 1` and `Amazon Root CA 2` use RSA public key, `Amazon Root CA 3` and `Amazon Root CA 4` use ECC public key.

This setup provides good level of flexibility, compatibility and security.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon lists 5 root CA on https://www.amazontrust.com/repository/ :

- [`CN=Amazon Root CA 1,O=Amazon,C=US`](https://censys.io/certificates/8ecde6884f3d87b1125ba31ac3fcb13d7016de7f57cc904fe1cb97c6ae98196e)
- [`CN=Amazon Root CA 2,O=Amazon,C=US`](https://censys.io/certificates/1ba5b2aa8c65401a82960118f80bec4f62304d83cec4713a19c39c011ea46db4)
- [`CN=Amazon Root CA 3,O=Amazon,C=US`](https://censys.io/certificates/18ce6cfe7bf14e60b2e347b8dfe868cb31d02ebb3ada271569f50343b46db3a4)
- [`CN=Amazon Root CA 4,O=Amazon,C=US`](https://censys.io/certificates/e35d28419ed02025cfa69038cd623962458da5c695fbdea3c22b0bfb25897092)
- [`CN=Starfield Services Root Certificate Authority - G2,O=Starfield Technologies\, Inc.,L=Scottsdale,ST=Arizona,C=US`](https://censys.io/certificates/28689b30e4c306aab53b027b29e36ad6dd1dcf4b953994482ca84bdc1ecac996)

Now I think "Starfield" was the CA that they bought to get into the CA game. And the other 4 Amazon made themselves.

And one difference I see is that CAs 1-4 all have different key types. (`Key Type 2048-bit RSA`, `Key Type 4096-bit RSA`, `Key Type ECDSA (P-256)`, `Key Type ECDSA (P-384)`.) That is a significant difference between then. Maybe there also are OTHER differences (such as intended usage maybe). But the key type alone makes the four CAs very different from one another.